# How to enable sorting in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.2

I'm searching for a way to enable sorting on property grid. I tried to put some "sortable" and "defaultSortable" to true at some places, but nothing happens.
Usually in ExtJS sortable is default why its is not working for me.

```
columns: [

        { header: 'Sample Name',  dataIndex: 'sample_name',flex: 1,sortable: true,
            editor: {
                allowBlank: true
            } },
        { header: 'Sample Type', dataIndex: 'sample_type',flex: 1,sortable: true,
            editor: {
                allowBlank: false
            } },
        { header: 'Text Code', dataIndex: 'text_code',flex: 1,sortable: true,
            editor: {
                allowBlank: false
            } },
]
```

Comment: Put together a fiddle.

Comment: [Grid](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) have default sorting available no need to apply property. you can here in my [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28te).
Have you tried [sortableColumns](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) property ?.

Comment: Yes I know it is having default sorting property but i don't know why it is not working for me.

Comment: I will  use sortableColumns property now

Comment: sortableColumns is also not working

Comment: @JammyNemo please provide your code on [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)

Comment: Yeah i will provide you

Comment: Sorry guys...actually i am working in huge project where only one grid is not sorting...I van't provide the code in fiddle.

Comment: The above code is the one i am using

Comment: do we have any property for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Ext.grid.Panel.
By default sortableColumns is true, see [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel)

Try this code in fiddle:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId:'simpsonsStore',
            fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data:{'items':[
                { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
                { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
                { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
                { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
            ]},
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'items'
                }
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [
                { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
                { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
                { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
            ],
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```